# Add rights to delete document in MarkLogic through Role

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a role called "monitoring" able to insert/view documents in MarkLogic. I want to add the right to delete documents but I don't know if I need to give it the "execute" privilege.

My role is the following :

```
<role>
  <role-name>moderators-role</role-name>
  <description>The role assigned to the zabbix user that monitor all server apps</description>
  <permissions>
    <permission>
      <capability>read</capability>
      <role-name>moderators-role</role-name>
    </permission>
    <permission>
      <capability>update</capability>
      <role-name>moderators-role</role-name>
    </permission>
  </permissions>
  <privileges>
    <privilege>
      <privilege-name>rest-writer</privilege-name>
    </privilege>
    <privilege>
      <privilege-name>rest-reader</privilege-name>
    </privilege>
  </privileges>
</role>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete a document, the user/role needs the document permission called 'update'. There is no particular execute role for this as it is related to the permissions of specific documents.

Check the permissions on a single document in question (xdmp:document-get-permissions) and see if your user such as rest-writer has an update permission on the document.

It should be noted that as long as these documents were not inserted by the admin role, then at least one update permission will already be present on the document.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer ! I check the document permission : the document has the "update" permission for the "rest-writer" role. But, when I check the "moderators-role" on the ML admin web UI, I see that "rest-writer" and "rest-reader" and not inherit in the "roles" section. They are only inherit for the "Execute Privileges" section.

Comment: What role writes the documents and what role do you want to delete the documents. The role of the user that writes the documents need to be granting the update privilege for the use that is meant to delete the documents.